# C# Mono Compiler doesn't work

Tags: c#, mono

I tried to install mono compiler using the following command:

```
pacman -S mono
```

The installation is completed successfully.

But when I try to compile this code (for testing-purposes):

```
using System;

public class Hello2
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

by using the following command:

```
mono myfile.cs
```

and in another way, by using this command:

```
mcs myfile.cs
```

For both methods, I get an empty output in the terminal.

Did I do something wrong? Why doesn't it work?

**Note:** I'm using ArchLinux

Comment: You ought to consider actually using the compiler, mcs.  [Read this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, just tried it. But I still get an empty output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the following two steps in order:

1. Compile your source code into an executable

   ```
   mcs -o myfile.exe myfile.cs
   ```
2. Run your compiled executable

   ```
   mono myfile.exe # ./myfile.exe should also work
   ```

Comment: I can't get it to work :(. I also installed monodevelop, when I try to execute it, it doesn't even start.

Comment: @jnajna12: note that you will not get any output from the `mcs` command. But running `mono myfile.exe` should either produce the output of your program or an error message why it could not be run.

Comment: I don't even see the .exe file. After compiling it, I also tried using mono command, I don't get nothing. I think there is a problem with the installation

Comment: What is the output of `mcs --help` and `mcs --version`? What is the output of `echo $?` after trying to compile your file?

Comment: the output of `mcs --help ` and `mcs --version` is empty, and the output of `echo $` is `$`

Comment: @jnajna12: empty output for `mcs --version` is very strange. `mcs` must be a different binary on your system then. Also, I asked for `echo $?` not `echo $`

Comment: the output of `echo $?` now is `0`.

Comment: @jnajna12: echo output aside. Your `mcs` is not the mono compiler. What man page is shown when you run `man mcs`?

Comment: I get on the terminal `Manual page mcs(1) line ?/? (END) (press h for help or q to quit)`

Comment: @jnajna12: are you sure that mono and the mono compiler (mcs) are properly installed on your system? (the package name is `mono` according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mono)

Comment: I didn't install mono from there. I just were on the terminal, and wrote: `pacman -S mono`, but it should be the same thing...

Comment: @jnajna12: what exactly solved the problem? The wiki page doesn't mention anything different than from what I told you/you claim to have already done.

Comment: Just backup'ed linux :P

Answer (score 0):

## `mcs`

`mcs` is a *compiler*, it translates the source code into intermediate code a *runtime environment* like `mono` can run. The compiler produces a file `file.exe` in the directory you've compiled it. Next you can run the file by calling it with `./file.exe`:

```
$ mv cstest.cs file.cs
$ mcs file.cs
$ ./file.exe
Hello World!
$
```

It will only print warnings, errors, etc. if such errors occur. Mind this is a compiler, not a runtime environment. For instance if you alter your file to:

```
using System;

public class Hello2 {
   public static int Main() {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

`mcs` will give an error:

```
$ mcs file.cs
file.cs(4,22): error CS0161: `Hello2.Main()': not all code paths return a value
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

## `mono`

`mono` is the runtime environment (as well as an ahead of time (AOT) compiler, but that's not relevant now). You can use `mono` to run the product of `mcs`:

```
$ mono file.exe
Hello World!
```

Comment: I can't get it to work :(. I also installed monodevelop, when I try to execute it, it doesn't even start.

Comment: @jnajna12: are you sure you've installed `mcs`? Is there for instance a manpage (`man mcs`) on your system?